# ping command packet size

Tags: ping

when i use ping command on linux

i get the following output :

```
    ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.205.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=490 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=1209 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=702 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=112 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=320 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=137 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=145 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=281 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=10 ttl=128 time=138 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=11 ttl=128 time=298 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=12 ttl=128 time=194 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=13 ttl=128 time=395 ms
64 bytes from mil04s29-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.205.206): icmp_seq=14 ttl=128 time=124 ms
```

so for the first line it says the size is 56 bytes (which is the size of icmp data right ?) + 8 (icmp header ) + 20 (ipv4 header ) = 84 bytes , which is the size of each sent packet right ?

no on the next line it says 64 bytes (data + icmp header) , why 64 bytes in replay why not 84 bytes ?!

in the last line

```
14 packets transmitted, 13 received, 7% packet loss, time 13607ms
```

what is time ? and how is calculated ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get the manpages (the "manual") for a package with the `man` command.**

If you run `man ping` in a terminal you will get a detailed description of the `ping` utility and instructions on how to use it.

In the manpage, there is the following entry:

> *ICMP PACKET DETAILS
> An IP header without options is 20 bytes.  An ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packet contains an additional 8 bytes worth of ICMP header  followed  by
> an  arbitrary amount of data.  When a packetsize is given, this indicated the size of this extra piece of data (the default is 56). **Thus
> the amount of data received inside of an IP packet of type ICMP ECHO_REPLY will always be 8 bytes more than  the  requested  data  space**
> (the ICMP header).*

**Oh, and time is calculated in milliseconds (ms)**

Comment: thanks for the answer , so the sent data is 56 bytes , and the received data is 8 bytes larger which makes it (64 bytes ) these numbers don't include the icmp header or the IP header right ?! , one last thing i know that time is in milliseconds ,but what i mean the number in the above example "time 13607ms"  how this number is calculated ?! 
Regards

Comment: per above, the default packet size of 56 bytes is for the "arbitrary amount of data" returned along with the 8 byte IMCP header.  The final tally is the total amount of time the ping utility took from start to finish -- (note that one of your packets was not returned, which can add considerable wait time)